# Setting responders for a Webview based document to solve unresponsive ui

Tags: xcode, cocoa, webview

I have a cocoa application where each document is basically a webview. It works very nicely, but I noticed that when I have a javascript routine running, the interface locks up. I downloaded the tutorial code from the apple docs, and in there, it works fine ! The only major difference I can still spot, is that the tutorial uses a single window and is not document-based.

so I am assuming that this is the culprit. However, I am totally lost in how to solve this

i've uploaded a screenshot here : (removed because i don't have 10 rep yet so i can only post one link) and you can see that I have two xib files : one for the app and one for the doc...

can anyone hint me how to handle this ?

EDIT : after crunching my brain for a whole night, i came to the conclusion that even on single window it doesn't work... I managed to make a very small test experiment here : http://noglangengelukkig.be/ex.zip

opening, compiling and running it will work fine, but as long as the network is stabilizing (= the nodes are still finding position), you can't click.

the page that it is showing is this one : http://www.beergraph.xyz so you can see that it works perfectly in safari !

Answer (score 0):

i found it... i'm an idiot... the reason things locked up was NOT webkit : it was the fact that the javascript code could not figure out which browser was running it, and thus assumed that setTimeOut() didn't exist and fell back to blocked-timing